# How can I put different route in my tabs with a singe html page in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have a one page with different content. I used JQuery to hide and show the content of the tabs. Then, when I tried `{{ url_for() }}` function to put in href, I always get `IntegrityError`.

html code:

```
            <li class="item">
                <a href="{{ url_for('user') }}" class="menu-btn overview-btn">
                    <i class="fas fa-desktop"></i><span>Overview</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="item" id="profile">
                <a href="#" class="menu-btn budgets-btn">
                    <i class="fas fa-coins"></i><span>Budgets</span>
                </a>
            </li>
```

The `{{ url_for('user') }}` is working but when I put `{{ url_for('add_budgets') }}` it gets an error.

routes.py:

```
@app.route("/add_budgets", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_budgets():
    form = BudgetForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit:
        user_budget = Budgets(budgets=form.budget.data, budget_id=current_user.id)
        db.session.add(user_budget)
        db.session.commit() 
        return redirect(url_for('user'))
    return render_template("user.html", form=form)

@app.route("/user", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def user():
    form = BudgetForm()
    posted_budget = Budgets.query.all()
    return render_template("user.html", title=current_user.username, form=form, posted_budget=posted_budget)
```

models.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from main import db, login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    current_budget = db.relationship('Budgets', backref='user_budget', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}')"

class Budgets(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    budgets = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    budget_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    expense = db.relationship('Expenses', backref='budget_expenses', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Budgets('{self.budgets}')"

class Expenses(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    categories = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    category_cost = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    category_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    expense_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('budgets.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Expenses('{self.categories}', '{self.category_cost}')"
```

error:

```
db.session.commit()

sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: budgets.budgets
[SQL: INSERT INTO budgets (budgets, date_posted, budget_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: (None, '2021-03-10 13:11:45.433302', 1)]
```

The argument budgets gets none even I already have budgets.

Comment: Can you add your database model.

Comment: @ConstantineWesterink, I edited and put my database model in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Print put all the values that you are trying the put into the database. And verify that the meet the requirements of the criteria in your db model.

one thing i notice is that you should have your id as your first argument and call it "id" and not "budget_id"

Comment: can you elaborate more about the id as first argument?

Comment: Im not exactly sure. It may not be needed. I guess im just accustomed to always do it like that. I believe flask sqlAlchemy sees the var ```id``` differently.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your error is due to the None value of the attribute "budgets". If you look at your error :

```
NOT NULL constraint failed
```

Meaning you are not allowed to have None as a value in your Database.
By the looks of your Budgets db Model.

```
budgets = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
```

And in the console error it shows that you inputed `None` as the value of `budgets`

```
[SQL: INSERT INTO budgets (budgets, date_posted, budget_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: (None, '2021-03-10 13:11:45.433302', 1)]
```

I believe that is where your error is coming from.

Comment: I see. Thank you. But now I found the problem which is the template inheritance of that route.